# Pointers confusion char* and int*

Tags: c++

I got this confusion while learning c++:

```
int *a = 8 ;
```

This gives an error because, as I have understood it, i am trying to set an integer to a pointer which is a memory location. But,

```
const char *name = "name";
```

works perfectly fine? I don't get it as name should be an hexadecimal memory location but i am trying to set it to a series of characters.

Comment: edited. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: use cast to void pointer `std::cout << (void*)name << std::endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string literal, `"name"` in your case, is of type`const char[]`. An array can decay to a pointer which is what's happening in this case. That pointer will then point to the first element in the array. Note that since C++11 assigning to a `char*` instead of a `const char*` (thus needing a conversion) as you are doing is illegal, always use `const char*` for string literals, or better yet, `std::string`.

`8` is of type `int`, which has no conversion to a pointer type that an array has.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for `int*` and `char*` are the same. However, you compare apples to oranges.

- You *cannot* assign a value of the respective type to its pointer (it doesn’t matter whether there is a `const` here; I made things `const` for consistency with the next example where it matters to some extend):

  ```
  int const*  ip = 8;   // ERROR
  char const* cp = ‘8’; // ERROR
  ```
- Arrays *decay* into pointers upon the slightest opportunity. String literals are arrays of type `char const[N]` where `N` is the number of `char`s in the string literal, including the terminating null `char`.

  ```
  int  ia[] = { 8 };
  char ca[] = { ‘8’ };
  int const*  ip = ia;   // OK
  char const* cp = ca;   // OK
  char const* lp = “8”;  // OK
  ```